# I have the image file even then FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] is found

Tags: python, image, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I am training an image captioning model on Google Colab. While doing that, I can't open an image when it is there. I printed out the image path and found no faults there. What is the wrong I'm doing here?

Here's the image_path:

```
/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Thesis/BanglaImageCaptioning/image&caption/validation/7330.png
```

Here's the script:

```
!python predict.py --path image_path --checkpoint '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Thesis/BanglaImageCaptioning/checkpoint.pth'
```

I can open the image with Image.open normally but it doesn't open with predict.py. I'm providing the predict.py below:

```
import torch

from transformers import BertTokenizer
from PIL import Image
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from models import caption
from datasets import coco, utils
from configuration import Config
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Image Captioning')
parser.add_argument('--path', type=str, help='path to image')
parser.add_argument('--checkpoint', type=str, help='checkpoint path')
args = parser.parse_args()
image_path = args.path
#version = args.v
checkpoint_path = args.checkpoint

config = Config()

# if version == 'v1':
#     model = torch.hub.load('saahiluppal/catr', 'v1', pretrained=True)
# elif version == 'v2':
#     model = torch.hub.load('saahiluppal/catr', 'v2', pretrained=True)
# elif version == 'v3':
#     model = torch.hub.load('saahiluppal/catr', 'v3', pretrained=True)  

# else:

print("Checking for checkpoint.")
if checkpoint_path is None:
  raise NotImplementedError('No model to chose from!')
else:
  if not os.path.exists(checkpoint_path):
    raise NotImplementedError('Give valid checkpoint path')
  print("Found checkpoint! Loading!")
  model,_ = caption.build_model(config)
  print("Loading Checkpoint...")
  checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_path, map_location='cuda')
  model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'])
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("sagorsarker/bangla-bert-base")

start_token = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenizer._cls_token)
end_token = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenizer._sep_token)

image = Image.open(image_path)
image = coco.val_transform(image)
image = image.unsqueeze(0)


def create_caption_and_mask(start_token, max_length):
    caption_template = torch.zeros((1, max_length), dtype=torch.long)
    mask_template = torch.ones((1, max_length), dtype=torch.bool)

    caption_template[:, 0] = start_token
    mask_template[:, 0] = False

    return caption_template, mask_template


caption, cap_mask = create_caption_and_mask(
    start_token, config.max_position_embeddings)


@torch.no_grad()
def evaluate():
    model.eval()
    for i in range(config.max_position_embeddings - 1):
        predictions = model(image, caption, cap_mask)
        predictions = predictions[:, i, :]
        predicted_id = torch.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)

        if predicted_id[0] == 102:
            return caption

        caption[:, i+1] = predicted_id[0]
        cap_mask[:, i+1] = False

    return caption


output = evaluate()




######################################
#print(tokenizer.decode(output[0][2]))
for i in range(len(output[0][1:16])):
  print(tokenizer.decode(output[0][i]))

########################################





result = tokenizer.decode(output[0].tolist(), skip_special_tokens=True)
#result = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
print("predicted caption: {}".format(result))
```

Here's the error msg:

```
Checking for checkpoint.
Found checkpoint! Loading!
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torchvision/models/_utils.py:208: UserWarning: The parameter 'pretrained' is deprecated since 0.13 and may be removed in the future, please use 'weights' instead.
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torchvision/models/_utils.py:223: UserWarning: Arguments other than a weight enum or `None` for 'weights' are deprecated since 0.13 and may be removed in the future. The current behavior is equivalent to passing `weights=ResNet101_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1`. You can also use `weights=ResNet101_Weights.DEFAULT` to get the most up-to-date weights.
  warnings.warn(msg)
Loading Checkpoint...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 47, in <module>
    image = Image.open(image_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2843, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image_path'
```

Comment: I think you can easily infer that image_path is taken literally and not expanded as a variable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is related to the way you're passing the image_path argument to your script.

In this line:
`!python predict.py --path image_path --checkpoint '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Thesis/BanglaImageCaptioning/checkpoint.pth'`

You're passing the string "image_path" as the argument instead of the actual path.

It should be:
`!python predict.py --path /content/gdrive/MyDrive/Thesis/BanglaImageCaptioning/image&caption/validation/7330.png --checkpoint '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Thesis/BanglaImageCaptioning/checkpoint.pth'`

So the full path to the image should be used in the command instead of a variable name
It would be a good idea to check if the image is there in the given path before trying to open it.

Also, the ! before python is not needed since it's running on the same runtime environment of the colab.
It will open the image correctly and perform the captioning task.